# Is there a method to use 'this' with 'assert()'?

Tags: c++, assert

I am trying to use 'this' inside of 'assert()', but it is giving  an error message.

Code:

```
assert(this == source);
```

Error:

```
pqueue1.cxx:62:29: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('PriorityQueue *' and 'const PriorityQueue')
                assert(this == source);
```

Comment: the issue is not from assert nor `this` but that you are trying to compare objects of different type where there is no `operator==` for them

Comment: The error message is saying that `source` is not a pointer to a `PriorityQueue`, while `this` is always a pointer. If you want to compare `this` with a pointer to `source`, it should be `this == &source`. However, from the question it is not exactly clear whether this is what you want since you are not giving any context.

Comment: Either you want to assert those are the same entity (`assert(this == &source)`) or they are the same value (`assert(*this == source)`).

Comment: `this` is a pointer, so may be compared with other pointers (to the same or compatible types of object).   The value of a pointer is the *address* of an object.   If `source` is an object, or a reference to an object, then `&source` is the address.    (Assuming `source` isn't a type that has defined an `operator&()`).

Comment: Since we do not know what exactly `source` is I've got feeling problem is located much deeper then comments or answer are trying to cover. I've try to close as "need debug details", but there were already 2 "typo" votes. If `source` is not reference then this is really bad (assert will never pass).

Answer (score 4):

The error has nothing to do with `assert` and has everything to do with the comparison. The message explains that you are trying to compare values of different types. One operand is a non-pointer object type and the other operand is a pointer to such type.

If you want to know whether `this` points to the object named by `source` (i.e. whether `source` is the instance whose member function is being called), then you can use the addressof operator to get a pointer to `source` and compare that with `this` pointer.

```
assert(this == &source);
```

If you want to know whether the object pointed by `this` compares equal with `source` (whether that is the same object or not), then you can indirect through the `this` pointer using the indirection operator:

```
assert(*this == source);
```

Comment: This `assert(this == &source);` makes seance only if `source` is a reference. I've got feeling it is not.

Comment: @MarekR It could be a non-reference  and the comparison still be potentially true if there is const casting involved. Aside from the constness difference, I don't see an issue. Nor do I see a reason to assume that `source` is a non-reference.

Comment: If this is not a reference then it is impossible assert to pass. IMO question lacks vital information.

Comment: @MarekR Works here: https://godbolt.org/z/jYd6xeKP1

Comment: I was planning to update comment with globals/static fields, but you were faster. Still question smells.